# How do I declare a NodeJs module in Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

My consuming Node code looks like this:

```
var helloworld = require('helloworld');
helloworld.sayhello();
```

Using the Typescript goodness, how would I declare the module exporting the `sayhello()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**helloworld.ts**

```
export function sayhello() {
    console.log('hello, world!');
}
```

Note that you would not write a containing `module` block (the file itself is the module).